# i am getting an error it is saying turtle object not callable

Tags: python, python-turtle

[image: the error message]

```
import turtle
import tkinter as tk
def importantmoving():
    win = turtle.Screen()
    win.title("moving")
    win.bgcolor("black")
    win.setup(width=800, height=800)
    win.tracer(0)
    #moving
    a = turtle.Turtle()
    a.speed(0)
    a.shape("square")
    a.color("white")
    a.shapesize(stretch_wid=5,stretch_len=5)
    a.penup()
    a.goto(0,0)
    #functions
    def a_up():
        y = a.ycor()
        y += 20
        a.sety(y)
    def a_down():
        y = a.ycor()
        y -= 20
        a.sety(y)
    def a_right():
        x = a.xcor()
        x += 20
        a.setx(x)
    def a_left():
        x = a.xcor()
        x -= 20
        a.setx(x)
    #keyboard binding
    win.listen()
    win.onkeypress(a,"Up")
    win.onkeypress(a,"Right")
    win.onkeypress(a,"Down")
    win.onkeypress(a,"Left")
    while True:
        win.update()

importantmoving()
```

and this is the code

i first tried to run my code see in which line my error was and the it came up with line 1921 and my code is 43 lines so i didn't know what to do so i ask here

Comment: You need to pass the functions to the keyboard callbacks, not the turtle object: `win.onkeypress(a_up, "Up")`, etc.

Comment: Please post your error as [text, not image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.onkeypress) -- `turtle.onkeypress(fun, key=None) Parameters: fun – a function with no arguments or None` but you passed a `Turtle` instance. The error is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the callback issue that @JohnnyMopp notes (+1), this code is poorly constructed.  The `while True:` loop is simply not needed nor desirable.  It's not clear why *everything* is bundled inside `importantmoving()`.  You also don't need to `import tkinter`.  Below is my rework of your code, see if it does what you intend:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def a_up():
    turtle.sety(turtle.ycor() + 20)

def a_down():
    turtle.sety(turtle.ycor() - 20)

def a_right():
    turtle.setx(turtle.xcor() + 20)

def a_left():
    turtle.setx(turtle.xcor() - 20)

screen = Screen()
screen.title("moving")
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.setup(width=800, height=800)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.shape('square')
turtle.shapesize(5)
turtle.color('white')
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.penup()

screen.onkeypress(a_up, 'Up')
screen.onkeypress(a_right, 'Right')
screen.onkeypress(a_down, 'Down')
screen.onkeypress(a_left, 'Left')

screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

check that You do not have a file with name turtle.py on your folder.
that was my problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).